# Set a global path variable that all functions use to save files to R

Tags: r, file, output, rscript

I have a simple problem I cannot find a simple solution for. I am using R for a data analysis pipeline and I want to set an output path as a global variable. This should then be used by various functions to save tables and plots. I want to avoid having to pass down this path-variable to each function. So what I did is the following:

```
outpath <- "../results/"
function1 <- function(){
    ... # analysis
    write.table(result, file = paste0(outpath,"/function1results.xls"))
    }
```

This runs fine if I just call function1() in Rstudio with the outpath-variable in the work environment. However if I want to run the whole script on another workstation with "Rscript" I get the following error:

> Error in as.vector(x, "character") :
>
> cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

I am assuming I am messing something up with how R handles the environments. Maybe someone has a better understanding than me :)

EDIT: It might be of interest that I am running windows on my local machine whereas the workstation runs linux.

Comment: That error (which is coming from `paste0()`) is telling you `outpath` is not defined in the environment. i.e. it's missing, or not in the global environment, or you used the wrong variable name in the function.

Comment: Adding on to what @hrbrmstr said, your `paste0` is going to yield "../results//function1results.xls". It's likely your path doesn't actually have double slashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the output path into the function

```
outpath <- "../results/"

function1 <- function(out){
    ... # analysis
    write.table(result, file = paste0(out,"/function1results.xls")
}

function1(outpath)
```

Comment: That does work, but I was trying to avoid that. I thought of using a global variable that should be accessible from inside a function.

Comment: If you really have to do that you could try using `<<-`, that is `a <<- "new"` or `assign("a", "new", envir = .GlobalEnv)`.

Answer (score 2):

Relative paths are a recipe for disaster, especially if the R script is not being run from the exact same location on all systems.

If you are *sure* — 100% *sure* — this script will *always* be run from a consistent location, then you can put:

```
outpath_prefix <- "../results/"
```

at the top of the script and use the `file.path()` function to join paths together in a platform-agnostic way:

```
file.path(outpath_prefix, "function1results.xls")
```

Read the help page (`?file.path`) on that function, specifically for this gem:

> The implementation is designed to be fast (faster than paste) as this function is used extensively in R itself.

HOWEVER

Consider using the "project" concept and install the `here` package.

Either use a proper "project" (i.e. the standard defined by RStudio) which places a "`project-name.Rproj`" in the root directory of the project or create one of these files (they can be empty) in the project root directory:

```
- `.here` 
- `.projectile`
```

*or* use version control for the project (which is *always* a good idea) and ensure the `.git` file is in the root directory of the project.

*Then* you can do:

```
outpath_prefix <- here::here("results")
```

at the top of *any* script in the project directory *regardless of depth* and still do:

```
file.path(outpath_prefix, "function1results.xls")
```

to get platform-agnostic, less-error-prone, and faster-generated path specs for input/output.

Comment: I am aware of the possible problems. I am however using relative paths to folders I am creating within the script. This should not change no matter where I run the script. I will try out the file.path function.

EDIT: Error in file.path(): argument "outpath_prefix" is missing, with no default

Comment: @hrbrmstr, how would we modify this, to just set the output path, without setting the name? Since some functions already have a predefined filename to be saved, most specifically, functions in "climatol" package, using homogen and daily2climatol functions. And in the documentation, no parameter is included to specify the output path. Sorry, if this sounds noobish, im coming from python and only using R for this specific package and could not figure it out.